# Run Stack Docker container

Tags: docker, haskell-stack

I'm confused about Stack's Docker integration.

I managed to create an image, by adding `docker` section to `stack.yml` with `enable: true`, as described in the [integration guide](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/docker_integration/).

I'm also able to start the project locally, by using

`stack --docker-run-args='--net=bridge --publish=8081:8081' exec myproject`

I navigate to localhost:8081 - works, great.

But how do I start the project using only Docker? With this I start the container:

`docker run -d --restart=always --net=bridge --publish=8081:8081 myproject`

But at this point nothing seems to be running. If I navigate to localhost:8081 I get connection refused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved!

It was missing to start the project in the container, as described in another part of [Stack's docs](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#docker). Specifically:

- Either start manually the executable, which is in `/usr/local/bin/` in the container (not very convenient)
- Or configure Stack to start the executable automatically by adding the following to stack.yaml:

  ```
  image:
    containers:
      -
        name: "myimage"
        base: "baseimage"
        entrypoints:
          - myexecutable
  ```

After this, run `stack image container` to build the image (it may also be necessary to run `stack build` before of this).

Then ensure the image was created / check name:

`docker image ls`

Finally, to run it:

```
docker run --net=bridge --publish=8081:8081 myimage
```